# How to setup selenium for python in docker?

Tags: python, docker, selenium, python-tesseract

How to setup selenium in docker in an ubuntu environment as I am also using tesseract for OCR and also flask.

How should I make my dockerfile?

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y \
    python3 \
    #python-setuptools \
    python3-pip \
    && apt-get clean \
    && apt-get autoremove

ADD . /home/App
WORKDIR /home/App
COPY requirements.txt ./
COPY . .

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

VOLUME ["/data"]
EXPOSE 5001
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]
CMD [ "app.py" ]
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you looked into this? https://hub.docker.com/r/davert/selenium-env